# How to convert From DateTime to unix timestamp in Flutter or Dart in general

Tags: flutter

as you seen in the title i want to convert from DateTime to unix Timestamp in Flutter (Dart Lang).

i saw the static Method that can convert from unix timestamp to DateTime :

```
DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(unixstamp);
```

i need the reverse

```
datatime => unixstamp
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Darts `DateTime` has a property `millisecondsSinceEpoch` which should be what unix timestamp is as well.

```
DateTime.now().toUtc().millisecondsSinceEpoch
```

Comment: Unix timestamps are in seconds, so you'll need to divide that by 1000.

Comment: ^ this should be the correct answer!

Answer (score 2):

`DateTime` provides `millisecondsSinceEpoch` and `microsecondsSinceEpoch` properties. For example:

```dart
var unixTimeMilliseconds = DateTime.now().toUtc().millisecondsSinceEpoch;
```

For whatever reason, there's no `secondsSinceEpoch`. Since traditional Unix timestamps are in seconds, you might also want this:

```dart
extension SecondsSinceEpoch on DateTime {
  int get secondsSinceEpoch => millisecondsSinceEpoch ~/ 1000;
}
```

Note the `~/` for integer division.

Answer (score -1):

```
String time = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString().substring(0, 10);
```

Mohamed ElSaraff answered this here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/72646505/12592516

I use this for Stripe API