# How to convert Flutter Date to TimeStamp?

Tags: android, ios, datetime, dart, flutter

I need to send a `post` request to the REST API where it includes a `Date` value. However the REST API and MySQL accepts a `Timestamp`. Below is how I prepare my current date

```
User user = User(
      name: nameTxtController.text,
      email: emailTxtController.text,
      phone: mobileTxtController.text,
      userLanguage: userLanguage,
      userRights: userRight,
      lastUpdated: DateTime.now(),
      dateCreated: DateTime.now()

    );
```

How to convert this to `Timestamp` ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Just do the following

```
User user = User(
      name: nameTxtController.text,
      email: emailTxtController.text,
      phone: mobileTxtController.text,
      userLanguage: userLanguage,
      userRights: userRight,
      lastUpdated: DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch,
      dateCreated: DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch

    );
```

for this to work, your `user.lastUpdated` and `user.dateCreated` should be of type `int` in your model (`bean` if you are from Java background) class

Comment: you should also mention how to convert it back to DateTime type

Comment: to covert it back -> DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(user.lastUpdated);

Comment: timestamp is in seconds so you need to do this: `(DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch / 1000).round()`

Answer (score 21):

**1) On pubspec.yaml**

Import cloud_firestore plugin with last version

https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/cloud_firestore

```
dependencies:
 flutter:
  sdk: flutter

 # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
 # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
 cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2`enter code here`

 cloud_firestore: ^0.9.13 //import this, with last version
```

**2) On your file.dart**

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
```

**3) DateTime to TimeStamp / TimeStamp to DateTime**

```
DateTime currentPhoneDate = DateTime.now(); //DateTime

Timestamp myTimeStamp = Timestamp.fromDate(currentPhoneDate); //To TimeStamp

DateTime myDateTime = myTimeStamp.toDate(); // TimeStamp to DateTime

print("current phone data is: $currentPhoneDate");
print("current phone data is: $myDateTime");
```

**4) Console**

```
I/flutter (15177): current phone data is: 2019-04-17 11:28:26.953530
I/flutter (15177): current phone data is: 2019-04-17 11:28:26.953530
```

**With your code**

```
User user = User(
  name: nameTxtController.text,
  email: emailTxtController.text,
  phone: mobileTxtController.text,
  userLanguage: userLanguage,
  userRights: userRight,
  lastUpdated: myTimeStamp //here
  dateCreated: myTimeStamp //here
);
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this once, it has worked for me

```
Timestamp.fromDate(DateTime.now())
```

here TimeStamp from [Cloud Fire Store](https://pub.dev/packages/cloud_firestore) Package and **needs to add this in pubspec.yaml file**.

Answer (score 5):

You can just use this without importing any package

```
String time = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString().substring(0, 10);
```